# Highlight the current date in cal

Tags: date, highlighting, cal

I would like to highlight today's date in the output of the `cal` command. What is the best way?

This is what I have so far:

```
cal -m | grep -C6 --color "$(date +%e)"
```

but it doesn't work for all cases e.g, when the date has a single digit. I also want the highlighting to work when I display the calendar for a year.

Comment: what specific version of UNIX are you using and what is the output of echo $TERM ?

Comment: Red Hat Linux / BSD Cal.

Comment: "BSD Cal" is the output of echo $TERM ?

Comment: $TERM is linux.

Comment: What version of Red Hat and cal, e.g. `cat /etc/redhat-release` and `rpm -q util-linux`.  This works out of the box on recent versions of Ubuntu and Fedora, so presumably you are using an old version.

Comment: @Mikel Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 7) and util-linux-2.11y-31.11

Comment: Is installing the latest version from source an option?

Comment: nope, as I don't have root access. I didn't think that searching for a date and surrounding it with a colour escape sequence would be that difficult. Surely grep or sed can do the job?

Answer (score 12):

I don't know how to highlight the day in the year calendar `cal -y` with just regular expressions, but the reason your example was not working for **single digit dates** is because `$(date +%e)` prepends a space to the output when the date has a single digit.

This will work:

```
cal | grep --color -EC6 "\b$(date +%e | sed "s/ //g")"
```

Comment: in __fish__: `cal | grep --color -EC6 "\b"(date +%e | sed "s/ //g")`

Comment: The command should be `cal | grep --color -EC6 "\b$(date +%e | sed 's/ //g')\b"` instead, otherwise, if the day of month is 1 or 2 there will be multiple 1x and 2x days get highlighted.

Answer (score 6):

`ncal -b` scratched this itch for me.

Answer (score 3):

On my system (openSUSE 11.4, util-linux-2.19), the current date in output form cal is automatically highlighted (reverse colors) if the output goes to terminal. As per the manpage, this seems to be the default. If it does not work on your system, it might be a bug.

Comment: There are many variants of `cal`, for example all three BSDs have different features. This isn't a bug in dogbane's cal, just a different implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The output is already highlighted, so you don't need to highlight it manually. In case you want it to work with grep, you need to disable it:

```
cal -mh | grep -C6 --color "$(date +%e)"
```

Comment: `cal  | grep -C6 --color "\b$(date +%e)\b"` ... need the boundary `\b` otherwise it will highlight chunks of the year too

Answer (score 1):

It may be fairly complicated to do something like this;
Why not try something like [pal](http://palcal.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the command `date +%-e` instead of `date +%e` to remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

For BSD systems **without** `grep --color` option:

```
B=$(tput bold)
U=$(tput sgr0)
DAY=$(date +%e | tr -d " ")
cal | sed -E -e "s|(.*[^0-9])($DAY)([^0-9].*)|\1$B\2$U\3|"
```

Oneliner:

```
cal | sed -E -e "s|(.*[^0-9])($(date +%e | tr -d " "))([^0-9].*)|\1$(tput bold)\2$(tput sgr0)\3|"
```

With week numbers left side:

```
cal -m -w | sed -E -e "s|(.*) ([[ 0-9]+])$|\2 \1|" -e "1,2s|^|     |" -e "s|(.*[^0-9])($(date +%e | tr -d " "))([^0-9].*)|\1$(tput bold)\2$(tput sgr0)\3|"
```