# highlight several dates in a year with gcal

Tags: date, cal

`cal` or `gcal` are linux terminal programs which display a calendar

`gcal 2023` displays the entire year 2023

This question explains how to make it highlight todays date in the current year -

[Highlight the current date in cal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11081/highlight-the-current-date-in-cal)

Does someone who is familiar with this program know if it is possible to give it a collection of dates in a year for it to highlight them all and how to do it?

Comment: I have since found solutions with python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485907/matplotlib-and-numpy-create-a-calendar-heatmap and after some research suspect it may not be possible with gcal anyway.